# Installing new packages created problems running Python and Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, installation-package

I was trying to install some new packages for a class this morning.

Before that I could run Jupyter fine. Now, I'm getting messages like, "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." in Jupyter and "'C:\Users\AceHer\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." in Anaconda.

I've tried reinstalling Python and Anaconda and following some suggestions on StackOverflow, but I know just enough to get myself in trouble, and not enough to get myself out. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Thanks. It appears to be in the right directory. I tried a simple code like 2 * 2 and Jupyter works.

I installed pydot through Anaconda, and it seemed to install correctly, then I tried to import pydot in a notebook and I get this error:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1b351e830afc> in <module>
----> 1 import pydot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydot'

Comment: Now that I installed the new version of Anaconda, I realized I have an Anaconda2 and an Anaconda3 version. I closed the Anaconda3 version and opened the 2 version. I installed pip successfully, but got this message.

"WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.9.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location."

Where is the PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're in the wrong directory. Sometimes I had these problems before but they were fixed after I changed directory. In your terminal, do this:

```
C:\Users\Username> cd directory/to/folder
```

Then try running your program after you get the right directory.

Comment: Thanks. It appears to be in the right directory. I tried a simple code like 2 * 2 and Jupyter works.